# Delete only specific verision of a column

Tags: hbase

I have a bunch of versions t1, t2, t3, t4 of a column.

The HBase doc [claims](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#version.delete):

> For this you can specify a version, or else by default the currentTimeMillis is used. What this means is delete all cells where the version is less than or equal to this version.

In the above case if I do `delete 'table', 'row', 'col', t3` all versions t1, t2 and t3 will be deleted.

But is it possible to delete only t3 so that t1 and t2 are got to keep?

Comment: have you checked this?

 "For an informative discussion on how deletes and versioning interact,
 see the thread [Put w/timestamp → Deleteall → Put w/ timestamp  fails](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/28421) up >on the user mailing list."

Comment: Yes. I saw this thread. It contains some trick to write a version prior deleted one, but it contains no answer to my question.
Well, there is a "tricky trick" first to delete versions and then to insert them again. But I still hope to find something more or less reasonable.

Comment: But probably you should change something in you general design. HBase is good at "write once and read many" scenarios. Deletes are also inserts which will create additional load, try to avoid them,or use TTL.

Comment: My design contains nothing special. I just want to keep all versions of each column. But sometimes the cells fall into the DB that have the same values and different versions. For example, val1(ts1), val2(ts2), val1(ts3) may be easily transformed to val1(ts1), val1(ts2), val1(ts3). I just want to clean up DB from such series. I want to make such cleanups weakly or monthly.
In general, it is disappointing that such exciting versioning system in of HBase is so strongly restricted by a such negligible restriction.
Well, it looks that I will have to keep tons of garbage.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from our discussion in comments section, you want to keep unique values of cells by deleting duplicates. You can do a common trick. Instead of tall table design you can switch to wide table design, by storing values in column names. There should be similar case in "HBase in Action" book. Thus you will eliminate duplicates on injection. Column name can contain as large data as column value.

Comment: No. I'd like to clean up not unique, but repeating values. A series v1, v1, v1 - is garbage and can be substituted by one v1, while v1, v2, v1 is necessary information.
Well, I see that there is no straight way to delete specific version.